How to skip django DeleteModel operation
I have deleted a model, Django creates a DeleteModel operation that I'd like to skip because i don't want to drop the table yet, but i also don't want to keep the model around. How can i skip dropping the table in this case but still delete the model?
I have tried commenting out the operation in the migration file but the next time you run makemigrations command the operation is recreated.

I don't really see what the problem is having the model around?

Bearing in mind the potential risk of having a database state that doesn't match your models, you may wish to reconsider deleting the model and retaining the table.
However, if you wish to go ahead, you can use the --fake flag when running a migration.
For example:
# Generate your migration file
python manage.py makemigrations

# Migration file generated with the name 0005_deletemodelname in the app test

# Fake running the migration
python manage.py migrate --fake test 0005_deletemodelname

Running a subsequent makemigrations command will not generate a new DeleteModel operation since Django considers the model to have already been dropped.

This is extremely unsafe: if the point is really to retain the model, then you'd want to make it skipped when applying to any environment, not requiring such special care. Answer by willeM_ Van Onsem is a safe alternative.

My understanding of the question is that the point is to retain the underlying table and get rid of the model: "i don't want to drop the table yet, but i also don't want to keep the model around."
If that is the case, then deleting the model code, generating a migration file and faking the migration would achieve the intended purpose in a fairly simple way.

Yeah, and now you deploy this code to another environment. You need to remember to run migrate --fake there, and you won't remember that in a couple of weeks, causing a data loss and going through painful backup restoration. My point is that, unlike a router solution, this won't persist in code and so can cause undesired consequences.

I don't really see the problem having a model in models.py you don't use, and thus acts as a placeholder.
But anyway, if you want to omit removing a model, you can plug in a custom database router preventing the actual migration:
# app_name/router.py


class PreventMigrationRouter:
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'my_app_label' and model_name == 'my_model_name':
            return False
        return None
with my_app_label and model_name the result of the model._meta.app_label and model._meta.model_name of the model you do not want to remove.
and then add your PreventMigrationRouter as first router in the DATABASE_ROUTER setting [Django-doc]:
# settings.py

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app_name.routers.PreventMigrationRouter']

When u create a model, Django create a table. If u don't need a model, just delete the table too, I couldn't imagine a scenario where u need a table but not the model for it. Even if u could do this, u couldn't manage the table anymore once u deleted the model (cause it's the "Django way" for CRUD operations on DB).
I think the best approach could be just don't use the model, or modify it when u will need a model for a future object of your project
